# Improving a suggested retag not enabling [I'm Done] button

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

I was working on the Suggested Edits queue and came across [a suggested retag](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1615332). The user had added 3 tags to the question. 2 tags were correct and 1 was unneeded. There were no edits to the content of the question. I clicked <kbd>Improve</kbd> to remove the extra tag but removing one tag is not enough to allow the <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> button to highlight and become available.

I decided to just skip the question as I wasn't sure if it should be approved or rejected based on this.
Was this the correct course of action and also should a retag option be added to Suggested Edits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no any button like <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> in Suggested Edits queue. When you click on <kbd>Improve</kbd> button. You can edit(improve) it via inline editor. And after editing, you actually need to click on <kbd>Save Edits</kbd> button available at bottom. When you click on it your review action is completed.

Comment: Wow, don't know how I missed that. Also thanks for teaching me how to add buttons to question text!

Answer (score 1):

In this case , I wonder is a removal not being counted as a change.

To get over this you could approve then go back & edit the question to remove the tag.